# Accessing Different Controller Method from A View with Ajax->form()

Tags: ajax, cakephp, controller

In my **conversations view**, I'm trying to make it so I can add **messages** to a conversation.

Currently I have a Conversation hasMany Messages relationship.

Now when I try to invoke the following code:

```
<?=$ajax->form('message','post',array('update'=>'messages')); ?>
```

It produces a form with a form action to

```
action="facebook/conversations/messages/add"
```

So I get an error saying I don't have the a controller function labeled "messages" in my conversations controller.

I want the action to go to my messages controller instead.

I'm sure its some really silly code I have to implement, but I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1366/form) you can also use a slightly different variant of the Ajax form function and avoid using the Html Helper to build the url.

```
$this->Ajax->form( array(
 'type' => 'post',
 'options' => array(
  'url' => array(
   'controller' => 'messages',
   'action' => 'action_name'
  )
 )
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. That helped significantly!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a url explicitly when you create a form.

```
echo $ajax->form('message', 'post', array('url'=>$html->url(array('controller'=>'messages', 'action'=>'action_name'))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I voted the link below because I feel like that resource was very helpful.